# Como passar o nome de uma janela wpf como parâmetro

Tags: c#, wpf

Utilizo um `userControl` customizado para mostrar um `Data Grid` e quando dou duplo clique em alguma linha, faço a chamada de uma janela de cadastro, que está esperando enviar o `ID` da linha selecionada como parâmetro, queria simplificar passando esse método de todas as telas de `Data Grid` para o `userControl` customizado como método virtual, então no duplo clique eu iria chamar só o método, só que não consigo passar o nome das janelas como parâmetro.

---

Exemplo falho do método virtual do userControl (na teoria seria isso)

```
public virtual void AbrirJanelaCadastro(Window window, DataGrid grid) 
{
    DataRow dataRow = (grid.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row;
    window(dataRow.Field<Int32>("ID")).ShowDialog();
}
```

Exemplo da chamada do método para abrir a janela no duplo clique

```
private void grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        AbrirJanelaCadastro(Cliente, Grid);
```

Comment: Explique por que o código é "falho". A questão não está clara o suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

na hora de chamar a Janela, instancie o objeto da janela a ser aberta e defina a propriedade Title

```
 Window1 w = new Window1();
 w.Title = "Seu Título";
 w.Show();
```

onde está "Seu Título"; você deve colocar o valor da sua DataRow

no seu código, poderia ficar assim:

```
 DataRow dataRow = (grid.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row;
 window.Title = dataRow.Field<Int32>("ID").ToString();
 window.ShowDialog();
```